# LocalStorage, Vuejs. Como recuperar e somar o valor de uma coluna jason/localstorage

Tags: json, vue.js, localstorage

Eu quero persistir localmente todas as somas(val*vezes) e somar todas os resultados de "soma" usando vuejs.

Dados a serem persistidos:

```
data: {
      nameApp: 'App',
      somaValor: {
        id: '',
        val: '',
        vezes: '',
        soma: ''
      },     
    },
```

Dados do localstorage

[image: localstorage já persistido]

Meu código

```
somarTotal(){
    let somaValores = localStorage.getItem('contactsApp');
    somaValores = JSON.parse(somaValores);   
    var t = 0; 
    var total = 0;

//Aqui quero o loop para pegar os valores da coluna soma e trazer o total;

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
        t = somaValores.soma;
                tarray[i] = t;
                console.log(tarray);
          
       return somaValores.push(soma);
}

for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { 
  total += tarray[i];               
                          
      }


  console.log(total);
    }
```

Observação:
Tentei o reduce mas não funcionou,
length também da erro..

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara. Por que está fazendo atribuição direta `tarray[i] = t` ao invés de usar `tarray.push(t)`? Por que está retornando (`return`) na primeira iteração do `for`?

Comment: Olá, grato pela dica. Consegui no Vuejs da seguinte forma.    
 computed: {
       total: function(){ 

var br = JSON.parse(numbers);  \\ aqui peguei o array
// aqui usei o metodo reduce
var g = br.reduce(function(previous, current) {
                    return previous + current.soma;
                  }, 0);
}


Dai soma os valores do meu Array e no meu tamplate eu mosrto o soma assim 
{{total}}

Comment: Gesser, não coloque sua solução na pergunta, coloque-a como resposta (abaixo do campo da pergunta, ao final da página, terá um botão "Responder à sua pergunta").

Comment: ok, @RafaelTavares

Answer (score 0):

Bom galera, eu resolvi assim:

```js
computed: { 
total: function(){ 
var br = JSON.parse(numbers); \\ aqui peguei o array // aqui usei o metodo reduce 
var g = br.reduce(function(previous, current) { return previous + current.soma; }, 0); }
```

Dai soma os valores do meu Array e no meu template eu mostro o soma assim

```js
{{total}}
```